# How to submit forms input values using post to server side script

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, post

I have a lot of buttons, each opens its form . How do I get the input value of form  opened at the moment, and post it on my server, like **post("/addOrders", valueOfinputs)?**

https://jsfiddle.net/ave6uvez/21/

```
                 <div class="rows">


  <div class="row">


    <button class="open">Buy</button>

      <form id="myform" action="/index" method="post">
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Name</label>
        <input type="namee"  name ="name" >
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="exampleInputPassword1">Phone</label>
        <input type="phone" name = "phone" >
      </div>

      <button  class="ave" >Close</button>
       <INPUT type="submit" id = "submit" class = "close" value="Submit">
   <!----   <button id="submit" class="close"></button>-->

    </form>


  </div>


</div>
```

Comment: Do you want the same server side script to handle all form submits or you want different forms submit to different scripts

Comment: I don't quite understand the question. My server side controller will handle   submit for one form and put values from form to database. From one form in which the  user will  click  submit.

Comment: Understood, you can use ajax. See my answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this,

```
$("#submit").click(function(e){
    $.post("/addOrders",$("#myForm").serialize());
    return null;
})
```

.serialize() will put all form elements data into the request

Also you need to give different id for different Forms submit button and you have to do the above code for each submit button

Hope this works for you.

Comment: Why i can't serialize like that: in $('.row').on('click',
  '.close',
  function(e) {$(this).parent('form').serialize();}

Comment: Yes you can, provided your button have different ids

Comment: I'm not using buttons id, just class in onclick function.

Answer (score 0):

This is a simple reference:

```
   // this is the id of the forms, set the form ids accordingly.
   $("#idForm").submit(function(e) {

 var url = "path/to/your/script.php"; // the script where you handle the form input.

$.ajax({
       type: "POST",
       url: url,
       data: $("#idForm").serialize(), // serializes the form's elements.
       success: function(data)
       {
           alert(data); // show response from the php script.
       }
     });

e.preventDefault(); // avoid to execute the actual submit of the form.
});
```